# Square terrain recurrence derivation

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

You have a square terrain with area $A > 0$. You want to add information into the terrain. You want to subdivide the terrain into $4$ quadrants, process them individually, and assemble the results. To process, you divide a quadrant further until the sub-quadrants have area $\le A_0$, where you can then add information to the terrain- all in total of $i\cdot A$ time for $i > 0$. Each subdivision step results in each of the four quadrants containing $\frac13$ the area (as they may overlap). If $T(A)$ is the time to label a terrain of area $A$, what is its recurrence?

I have an answer as 
$$4T(\frac{\frac{A}{A_0}}{3})+iA,$$
but I don't understand how it was derived. Can someone explain how each component of the problem relates to an addition in the final result? I understand the $4$ recursive calls, but not much after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of the [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). If you are looking for a proof, [this link from wikipedia](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section5-2.pdf) seems promising.